# Curl is giving me an error and only removing CURLOPT_USERAGENT and CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER it works

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to make this to work, but it only works if I remove the two lines that are commented out. If I enable it stops working with a Error 404 (Not Found). Why?

Thanks in advance.

```
$headers = [
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language: pt-PT,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'Cache-Control: no-cache',
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
    'Host: httpbin.org',
    'Referer: http://www.google.com', 
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36',
    'X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true',
    'X-Amzn-Trace-Id: Root=1-60e1dc05-44eb1f0a7cff152139d79c76'
];

$url = $_POST['URL'];   
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com');
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$get = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Instead of “stops working”, please explain the expected outcome as well as the actual outcome. Also, make sure error reporting is turned all the way on.

Comment: When I add the lines that are commented out I get a Error 404 (Not Found). When I remove those lines all works just fine. Thanks

Comment: Try adding the headers back in but as an empty array

Comment: I comment out the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER so the header will have no effect, but if I enable the CURLOPT_USERAGENT I get the error.

Investigating a little further I get this: when I comment out those lines the URLs is fetched like this: https://www.example.com/something/id

But If I enable those lines the URL is fetched like this: something/id and that what is causing the error. Now, why is this happening?

Don't now if this information is relevant, but I'm doing this on a localhost using xampp

Thanks

Comment: I managed to make it work with CURLOPT_USERAGENT enabled by adding also the line curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
But still can't make the line CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER to work.

Comment: Try removing the host header, it is rare to actually need to do this, curl should handle it for you. If that doesn’t, try an empty array for the headers, then add each one back manually, one at a time

Comment: Thanks Chris... I was able to make it work only with the first one "Accept". Regards